# What is your favorite estimation exercise?

Tags: soft-question

A fun question I ask students or interviewees (in engineering) is:

> **This is not my question, this is an example:**
>   Using only what you know now, how many
>   cans of soda would you estimate are
>   produced per day (on average) in the
>   United States?

For this question, the result doesn't matter so much as the process you use.

In this theme of estimation, what's your favorite question?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_problem

Comment: [This](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-098-street-fighting-mathematics-january-iap-2008/) may be of interest.

Comment: I voted to close because I don't think this question is math-related. No math-related answers either.

Comment: In my defense...it was CW

Answer (score 18):

"How many estimation questions are asked in interviews across the world during a typical 24h period?"

Comment: I see what you did there...

Comment: I find it bothersome that out of all answers I posted on this site, this "smartass answer" is by far the most up-voted.

Answer (score 4):

One that I remember from some book (I think it was Innumeracy by John Allen Paulos) was "How fast does your hair grow, in miles per hour?"

Comment: This seems more like a factor-label problem to me, but I like it

Answer (score 0):

I like "how many licks does it take to get to the center of a tootsie roll pop".